# How to move App to Applications folder when running it?

Tags: applescript-objc

What I'm trying to do is that when the user runs the App from outside the Applications folder, a display alert appears asking if he wants to move the App to the Applications folder if the App is not already there.
I tried the following:

```
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        set myApp to path of document 1
        set folderApplications to "/Applications" as POSIX file
        set anyApp to "/Applications/My.app" as POSIX file
        tell application "Finder"
            if exists anyApp then
                display alert "There is already an App with the same name in Applications Folder.
                return
                else
                tell application "System Events"
                    move myApp to folderApplications
                end tell
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
```

ERROR: Can’t get «class FTPc» of document 1. (error -1728)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work for you. The code must first be saved as an application named "myApp.app", for this to function correctly.

```
property myName : "myApp.app"

set folderApplications to path to applications folder as text
set pathToMe to path to me as text

tell application "Finder"
    set appExists to exists of alias (folderApplications & myName)
end tell

if not appExists then
    beep 3
    set moveApp to button returned of (display dialog ¬
        "Would You Like To Move This App To The Applications Folder?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} ¬
        default button 2 ¬
        with title "Move This App?")

    if moveApp is "Yes" then
        tell application "Finder"
            move alias pathToMe ¬
                to alias folderApplications
        end tell
    end if

end if

-- the rest of your code
```

Comment: Yes, it works but I need to implement within:
```on applicationWillFinishLaunching: aNotification```
so that when the App is opened it displays an alert
asking if the user wants to move the App inside
Applications folder.

Comment: I can't really help with applescript-objc but maybe my updated code can point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can thank me by either up voting and or accepting my post ;-)